# fetch from API - specific API errors vs general HTTP errors

Tags: javascript, http

I am using fetch() to get results from an API. As I understand it, there's 2 different types of errors:

- an error that my API returns specifically: for example "invalid authentication token"
- more generic HTTP errors: for example - network timeout or connectivity was interrupted.

Is there a way to determine the nature of the issue, in such a way that I can retry an API command when it makes sense (like poor network connectivity), but not retry it if it's just going to give the same result as the previous time (like an invalid token error)

Comment: `fetch()` only throws if there was some network error. If your server responded with an error status, you'd have to check it in the `then()` block.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! So in general if i enter my catch() block of the fetch(), I can treat that as a network issue?

Comment: If you land in the `then()` part, your server has responded successfully; wether you like that response or not. If you land in the `catch()` part of the `fetch()`, something went wrong and a network error is one of the more likely reasons.

Comment: @Thomas perfect - can you supply this as an answer, not a comment, so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to determine the nature of the issue, in such a way that I can retry an API command when it makes sense (like poor network connectivity), but not retry it if it's just going to give the same result as the previous time (like an invalid token error)

`fetch()` only throws if there was some error with recieving the data. If your server responded with an error status, you'd have to check that in the `then()` block.

> @Thomas Thanks! So in general if i enter my catch() block of the fetch(), I can treat that as a network issue?

Think the other way around. If you land in the `then()` part, your server has responded successfully; wether you like that response *(200)* or not *(404)*.

If you land in the `catch()` part of the `fetch()`, something went wrong with the request and a network error is one of the more likely reasons. An invalid url, like `"//"`, would be another reason to throw.